# Applying perturbed matrix to unperturbed eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Suppose we've got a matrix $P$ and a perturbed version $\hat{P}=P+E.$ Given that $v$ is an eigenvector of $P$ with $Pv=0,$ I'd like to get as sharp a bound as possible on $\hat{P}v$ (in terms of whatever perturbation-measure is most appropriate.

I could write $\hat{P}v = \hat{P}\hat{v} + \hat{P}(v-\hat{v})$ for the eigenvector $\hat{v}$ of $\hat{P}$ corresponding to $v$ (i.e. the eigenvector whose associated eigenvalue is smallest) and then apply classical perturbation theorems to both expressions, but this seems crude and also to miss the point. I feel like working with a zero-eigenvalue should allow me to find a better bound, somehow.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated, guys!

Comment: I think that you will need a certain amount of additional information to be able to say almost anything useful, because although the map from $A$ to its (algebraic) eigenvalues is quite nice everywhere (provided you choose the right space for the "eigenvalue-vectors" to live in), the map from $A$ to its eigenvectors is actually rather ill-behaved. In particular you will find that it has singularities at eigenvalues of multiplicity higher than 1. (Consider, for example, the parameter dependence of the eigenvectors of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1+\varepsilon \end{bmatrix}$.)

Comment: (Cont.) If you assume that $A$ has all distinct eigenvalues, then perturbations by small enough amounts will have distinct eigenvalues the whole way. Then everything is nice, as I recall.

Comment: A revision to that first comment: I should say that the eigenvector map *may* have singularities when the multiplicity is higher than 1. It definitely will when approaching a defective matrix (as in my example above), but I am not so sure when approaching a diagonalizable matrix with a double eigenvalue.

Comment: Actually, we can assume that $P$ will have $0$ as a repeated eigenvalue. Apparently this will make things a lot harder, but (in relevance to your last comment) we can assume that the zero-eigenvectors are all linearly independent.

Comment: If $0$ is not a repeated eigenvalue then everything is classical. If it is then you may have problems; for example, you can look at $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \varepsilon \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Here the unperturbed matrix is diagonalizable but the perturbed matrix is not.

Comment: Why not just use $\hat Pv = Pv+(\hat P-P)v = Ev$? This seems the tightest without further assumptions on structures of $E$.